# How to read excel file tibco activities?

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I have a requirement to read excel file using tibco palettes.Can any body please throw some lights regarding this. I am basically new to this tibco BW. Please tell me what steps should I follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are not referring to CSV files, for which you could use the File Read and Parse activities of BW. 
If you want to parse or render a multi-worksheet workbook, you can try publicly available API's such as [Apache's POI](http://poi.apache.org) or commercial API's such as from Aspose to cut your own Java based solution. Then you can use the Java Code or general Java activities to embed and use that code.

And then there's another ready-to-use option available from us: an [Excel Plugin for TIBCO BusinessWorks](http://www.appsmatters.com/products/excel-plugin/index.htm), if you wish to leverage all built-in features of BW (XPath mapping, etc) when parsing or rendering your Excel.

**Edit 1:**
As per your comment, you can also try the following steps, if you are looking for a more homegrown solution.
Based on one of the (public/commercial) libraries above you can write generic Java Code to parse each cell of each row of each sheet of the workbook. Output should be an XML string. Then create an XSD to match your output. It is at your discretion, which information of the cell you want to read from the workbook - you already are aware of the complexity of the API, I am sure.
Create a BW (sub)process that calls your code from a Java activity, use Parse XML to parse your XML string result into you XSD structure. Configure the End activity to use your XSD and map (copy) your Parse XML result into the End activity.
Then wrap this subprocess into a Custom Activity (General Activities Palette). Create a Custom Palette and now you can re-use what you did in many other BW projects. The path to the custom palettes can be found in TIBCO Designer - Edit- Preferences - General - User Directories
If you add Error Output schemas, you will also get typed error outputs from that custom activity.

HTH,

Hendrik

Comment: Thanks for answering.I have already done using java code activity.Now just looking for some other ways.Can you tell me if it is possible to create our own activity so that I will not use java code activity any more.Because each time I use java code activity then I have to write codes for it.

Comment: added an alternative approach to use Java and BW-only features for building a re-usable component.

Comment: Thanks for answering.I have accepted your answer.Well do you have a gmail so that I can ask you later when I find any problems

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I am not using GMail, but you can reach me via our website (see above), if required.

Comment: which is your website and how to reach?do you work in `appsmatters.com`